# What is the proper way of running selenium grid?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

I'm learning and tinkering with selenium in java and have a little bit of confusion when it comes to selenium grid. as per the standard procedure, one is supposed to run a grid hub and multiple grid nodes which in turn connect to the hub, and in the code, one is supposed to set requirements like browser, version, os platform etc and submit it to the hub, which in turn forwards it to a node with the proper setup. What i've seen is that my code works both when I connect to the hub or the node directly. So my question is, which is the proper way of running grid ? Run a hub, submit the job to it and let it decide which node to forward the job to, or dispense with the hub and keep track of different nodes and their capabilities in the code itself, perhaps as property file entries, so that the job can directly be submitted to a node according to the requirement. Forgive me if this question is incredibly stupid, but i'm just a newbie here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically main goal of selenium grid is run test from hub and check in all connected nodes. Node can be single or multiple. So best way is setup one pc as HUB and others as NODE(S).

You can run test in multiple OS and browsers from hub.So its depends on you and your test case that on which node you want to run test?

For ex: If you have 3 nodes with diff. browsers like :

> Node 1 : Firefox
>   Node 2 : Chrome
>   Node 3 : Safari

Now assume that all above nodes are connected with your hub so if you want to test website in all 3 browsers then you can run all nodes from hub and if you want to check website in only chrome and safari then you need to run only 2nd and 3rd node.

Hope above example have clear your all confusions.